# python function with multiprocessing can not run after compiling with cython

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-3.6, cython

I have some problem with cython，the function of my script is as below：

```py
class A(object):

    @staticmethod
    def subprocess_func(split_data):
        do something

def multi_process(process_func, datas, process_num, *args):
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    out_q = manager.Queue(process_num)


    p = Pool(process_num)
    each_num = math.ceil(len(datas)/process_num)
    for i in range(process_num):
        split_data = datas[i * each_num: (i + 1) * each_num]
        p.apply_async(A.subprocess_func, args=(split_data,))
```

`process_func` is a static method of class `A`, when not compiling with `cython`, it works. But after compiling with `cython`, it gets stuck after calling function `multi_process` and cannot enter `subprocess_func` without have any logs.

However, when I move function `subprocess_func` outside of class `A`, it both works when compiling with `cython` or not.

cython: v0.29.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced this problem recently as well. You can not pass a static method when compiling your code with Cython. The solution for me was to move my static methods that are mp based outside of the class. Arguably this was a good call anyways, and made the code more readable.

Comment: Did you ever find out why this is? Perhaps worth creating an issue in their issue tracker? Sounds like it's a bit broken or there's a really good reason why this isn't possible hehe.

Comment: @Robert Kearns I solved the problem as what you said, but what makes this problem happen? Though the code is more readable, I have to move all methods like **subprocess_func** and methods called in function **subprocess_func** outside of class A.